# How to remove the given columns and strings?

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Consider a data having the form

```
data={{P,4,3,2},{V,7,8,9,55},{P,19,3,4},{V,48,6,1,55}}
```

How to remove all rows with V and then to remove the first column, i.e., to get

```
dataprime={{4,3,2},{19,3,4}}
```

Comment: e.g. `Cases[data, {Except[V], rest__} :> {rest}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[data, {V, ___}][[All, 2 ;;]]
```

> {{4, 3, 2}, {19, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{P, 4, 3, 2}, {V, 7, 8, 9, 55}, {P, 19, 3, 4}, {V, 48, 6, 1, 55}};
```

Two other possibilities

```
Cases[data, {P, a__} :> {a}]
```

{{4, 3, 2}, {19, 3, 4}}

```
Rest @@@ SequenceSplit[data, {{V, __}}]
```

{{4, 3, 2}, {19, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{P, 4, 3, 2}, {V, 7, 8, 9, 55}, {P, 19, 3, 4}, {V, 48, 6, 1, 55}};
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[data, {s : {P, __}} :> Rest@s]

(*{4, 3, 2}, {19, 3, 4}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[data, {___, s : {P, __}, ___} :> Rest@s]

(*{4, 3, 2}, {19, 3, 4}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

data = {{P, 4, 3, 2}, {V, 7, 8, 9, 55}, {P, 19, 3, 4}, {V, 48, 6, 1,
55}}

**Using `Select`:**

```
data // Select[First@# =!= V &] // Map[Rest]
```

**Using `Pick`:**

```
Rest /@ Pick[data, First@# =!= V & /@ data]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{4, 3, 2}, {19, 3, 4}}